# Help creating a texture for cookie - not sure how to improve texture bump with my simple texture node tree

Tags: texturing, shaders, sculpting

I am trying to recreate this cookie:
[image]

but I am stuck on how to create this crumbly/cracking like texture. I am using the Voronoi Texture -> Bump, which I think gives me a good starting point in creating that crackly-kind of texture, but I am stuck; not sure how to proceed or improve beyond this. I'm not sure how to get that texture to 'pop'  I've done the donut tutorial, but i am new to blender. Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far from perfect (it would probably be better to use a photo as texture and sculpt) but you can try the *Voronoi* in *Distance to Edge* mode, twist the *Mapping* a bit with a *Noise Texture*:

[image]

File here: [image]

Comment: wow LOL. this is incredible. I will study what you have did and replicate it in my own file. not looking for perfect since i am starting out, but the use of all those nodes is great. I'm still learning how to use the input/output between those nodes, so this will be a good learning exp. thank you so much

Comment: Which version of blender are you using? i'm using blender 3.6.5. I tried replicating your efforts on my file, but my cookie doesnt look like yours at all, but i tweaked some of the settings to create another texture that i find acceptable for now. I noticed you also used a cube, i'm using a cylinder. Is there any reason why you chose a cube? Thank you again

Comment: please share your file so that I check your material. I've begun with a cube that I subdivided to have a coherent density on the whole object

Comment: My file is available here: https://blend-exchange.com/b/2Go3oEe8

Comment: here is my blend file https://blend-exchange.com/b/P0DmOv8L. your comment about the cube makes sense. I subdiv a cylinder and I honestly don't like how the geometry looks in edit mode; looks weird, but i dont know enough to make the right judgement on it. I'm considering restarting with a cube since sculpting this shape is very easy work. Let me know your thoughts. thank you.

Comment: Begin with a cube, in Edit mode right click > Subdivide and in the Operator Box choose the subdivision level and put the Smoothness at 1 to have a spherical shape, then flatten on Z, sculpt, etc

Comment: Your object is pretty small, so the Noise and Voronoi values probably don't fit, also its scale is not 1:1:1 so apply the scale and change the values or scale it up and apply the Scale, also the ColorRamp colors should be a bit more contrasted, they are a bit too close for the moment

Comment: I've recreated my cookie with a cube and applied your suggestions to that cube. I've also increased the scale. I'll keep in mind scaling; and that I dont need to scale true to size, at least for now as I learn.  My cookie does look more like yours now, yours is still better, but what I have is good enough. Youve been super helpful, I appreciate your time and I hope to see you again :) thank you

Comment: you're welcome   ;) .............